# Not getting push notification when swipe from recent

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I'm not getting notification when user swipe the app from recent. I've notice that behavior occurs in some specific device for instance I've tested it on nexus devices and HTC devices it's working fine but when user swipe the app from the recent in huawei and some samsung devices it doesn't show notification. I mean i don't get `onMessageReceived()` callback

After some research I found out that in these devices when user swipe it from recent it force stop the app (the process is completely killed) and I don't get any notification. In huawei they have protected and unprotected apps and if I add the app in protected list from the setting, I start getting notification because i this case it doesn't force stop the app. and I believe in samsung they have the same thing with blacklist and whitelist apps.

I've also tried some solutions like restart the service o`nTaskRemoved()` callbacks or make your app `START_STICKY`. I've also tried `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` but nothing is working for me.

So my question is how can i get notification even if it gets forced stop, like it's happening when swiping app from recent.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I think it’s important to know that HUAWEI has a feature called “power-intensive app monitor “. It kills every app that runs in the background for a long time unless user gives special permissions to it. 
The path to do this:
Settings -> Security & privacy -> Location services -> recent location requests: YOUR APP NAME -> Battery -> uncheck Power-intensive prompt, App launch: Manage manually: check all three positions: Auto-launch, secondary launch, run in background.

I don’t know if there's a way to do this programmatically. I think the best way is to create a sort of help activity and explain the user what to do if application won’t work.